# Why is Cambrian denoted with such a weird symbol?

Tags: geology, time

I find Ꞓ such an odd-looking symbol. What's the historical significance, etc, of that symbol?

> Latin letter C with bar
>   [image]

My understanding is, C was the Carboniferous, K for Cretaceous... why not just use a different letter?

Comment: I suspect it is simply because it looks like a C but is distinguishable from the Carbaniferous, but am interested to see if there are documented answers. As a side note, it is used in other languages. Symbols come and go and what looks weird today may have been more recognised in earlier times.

Comment: A lot of geological symbols are based on the assumption of hand drawn maps and sections. Geology has many unique symbols.  once you know that simply creating a new symbol based on C would make more sense than using some random letter. Not that there are that many letters left.

Comment: Cretaceous [is usually abbreviated K, for its German translation Kreide.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cretaceous)